# How to handle IOException in Spring webflux?

Tags: exception, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to retreive byte[] from my Mono but using getBytes() method it shows unhandled IOException. How do I handle it in my reactive code?

My service layer

```
public HttpStatus excel(Mono<MultipartFile> filePartMono) {
        Excel t = new Excel();
        t.setExcel(filePartMono.map(filepart-> {
            try {
                return filepart.getBytes();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            return new **byte[];** //doing this here it shows array initializer expected what does it mean 
        }));
    excelRepository.save(t);
        return HttpStatus.ACCEPTED>;
```

Comment: Where's your stack trace?

Comment: I'm also guessing that this is not a reactive repository as you are passing in an Excel instance instead of a Mono/Flux. If you are wanting to have a fully reactive app, you should look at using a reactive db driver.